# How to configure Azure Blob Storage with SFTP for Inbound File Transfer Activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, sftp, azure

I have one doubt related to Automation Studio

Wanted to do SFTP using Azure Blob Storage
I have done setup following steps :-

1. Created Azure Blob storage with SFTP Access
2. In automation added Schedule Activity and then added file transfer
   activity (As I wanted to schedule automation after transferring file
   from blob storage to MC FTP using filezilla)
3. For this, I setup File locations and gave URL of cloud and password but, blob storage has container and there is subfolder where I added .csv data
4. After running it is giving me this error, Error Message: File not
   found matching the pattern
   sftp://azureblobcoupon.blob.core.windows.net:22/Customer.csv (
   Actually the csv is inside container/subfolder/Customer.csv)
5. And when I give file location as  azureblobcoupon.blob.core.windows.net/subfolder It gives error message Error Message: File not found matching the pattern sftp://azureblobcoupon.blob.core.windows.net/subfolder/Customer.csv
6. And when I give file location as
   azureblobcoupon.blob.core.windows.net/container/ It gives error
   message Error Message: An undefined error occurred. Contact your
   account representative if the error persists.
7. File Naming pattern did not able to redirect container and then subfolder as it only takes 'wildcard specifiers'

what am I doing wrong here?

My use case is to get data from client via .csv and then use that data in marketing cloud using azure enabled sftp.